# Magento 2 Can't Convert Data Convert From quote_item to order_item Table Using Field-set

Tags: magento2, database, conversion

Can Anyone Please Help me to data convert quote_item to order_item Table Using Field-set.

First I am Create file ***etc/extension_attributes.xml*** and use code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
        <attribute code="temp_id" type="decimal"/> 
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

After Create Another File in ***etc/fieldset.xml*** and put code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
<scope id="global">
<fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_item">
<field name="temp_id">
<aspect name="to_sales_order_item"/>
</field>
</fieldset>
</scope>
</config>
```

and also created the column in both tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Follow This Step(DevDocs)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ext-best-practices/tutorials/copy-fieldsets.html)

**etc/fieldset.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
        <scope id="global">
            <!-- Copy quote to sale order fields -->
            <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote">
                <field name="your_field">
                    <aspect name="to_order" />
                </field>
            </fieldset>
        </scope>
    </config>
```

> Seem that we need to use Observer
>   sales_model_service_quote_submit_before to assign the new fields:

Comment: thank you for using the observe working perfectly ...

Comment: happy coding bro ..... :)